# How to make stock quantity of a different product decrease, when a product is bought?

Tags: stock, quantity

When an item is bought, the quantity for THAT item will decrease by 1, how could I make it so ANOTHER item also decreases by 1.

For example, on my website, I will be selling computer parts individually, but also, I will be selling assembled computers aswell, the assembled computer will use components of the computer parts, hence when someone purchases an assembled computer, the stock for that, and the used computer parts should all decrease, as to manage my stock quantities properly.

Answer (score 2):

Use configurable products for this and you wont have to code anything. See [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product) for some more info about them.
If you have doubts, install the official sample data, it has this kind of products already configured with the exact case you need.

Comment: I fail to see how configurable products will help in my case. :/

Comment: Configurable products are made of simple products. So if you sell a computer, monotir is a single product, processor is a single product, RAM is a single product, etc. When you buy a complete computer (configurable product) it will be composed with simple products with stock, so the stock of the simple products will decrease once the purchase is made.

Comment: How would I hide the dropdown options? I want it so it appears as a simple product to the end user instead of configurable. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Add only one option and mark it as default. See http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12810/selecting-default-option-for-configurable-product

Answer (score 0):

Best way here is to use Bundle Product with selectable options per component of the bundle. Here is an example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yCbxbcCUCM